# Create a hierarchical data structure from a flat list with parent_id

Tags: elixir

I have a list of data structures like this:

```
defmodule Foo do
  defstruct [:id, :parent_id, :children]
end

lst = [
  %Foo{id: 1, parent_id: nil, children: []},
  %Foo{id: 2, parent_id: 1, children: []},
  %Foo{id: 4, parent_id: 1, children: []},
  %Foo{id: 3, parent_id: 2, children: []},
]
```

The list is sorted by `parent_id` and `id`, so the lower `parent_id`s are earlier in the list than the lower `id`s. I want to transform that list to a hierarchical data structure:

```
  %Foo{id: 1, parent_id: nil, children: [
    %Foo{id: 2, parent_id: 1, children: [
      %Foo{id: 3, parent_id: 2, children: []},
    ]},
    %Foo{id: 4, parent_id: 1, children: []}
  ]}
```

I had a naive idea with a recursive loop and `Enum.filter`, but this seems pretty inefficient. Any ideas how to solve this efficiently?

**Edit**:

I seem to have a working solution, but it is pretty inefficient as well:

```
defp build_tree(root, []), do: root
defp build_tree(root, [node | tail]) do
  build_tree(insert_node(root, node), tail)
end

defp insert_node(root = %Message{}, node) do
  if root.message_id == node.parent_id do
    new_messages = case root.messages do
                     nil ->
                       [node]
                     _ ->
                       root.messages ++ [node]
                   end

    %Message{root | messages: new_messages}
  else
    acc = case root.messages do
            nil -> []
            _ -> root.messages
          end

    %Message{root | messages: insert_node(acc, node)}
  end
end

defp insert_node(root, node) do
  Enum.map(root, fn(x) -> insert_node(x, node) end)
end

[first | rest] = sorted_messages
tree = build_tree(first, rest)
```

Any ideas for a better solution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since the records are sorted by `parent_id` and then `id`, here's one fairly efficient way. It involves iterating through the list only twice: one reverse and one reduce. The reduce itself does some Map operations, but they're still only `O(log n)`, so the whole thing is `O(n log n)`:

```
tree =
  list
  |> Enum.reverse
  |> Enum.reduce(%{}, fn foo, map ->
    foo = %{foo | children: Map.get(map, foo.id, [])}
    Map.update(map, foo.parent_id, [foo], fn foos -> [foo | foos] end)
  end)
  |> Map.get(nil)
  |> hd
```

The core idea is that we keep a temporary map keyed by the `parent_id` of `Foo`, and whenever we see that the current Foo's `id` is present in the map, we take its `children` out and put it in the current `Foo`, and then insert the current `Foo` in the `children` of its `parent_id`. Finally, we take out the only `Foo` which has `parent_id: nil`, and use that.

Demo:

```
defmodule Foo do
  defstruct [:id, :parent_id, :children]
end

defmodule Main do
  def main do
    list =
      [%Foo{id: 1, parent_id: nil, children: []},
       %Foo{id: 2, parent_id: 1, children: []},
       %Foo{id: 4, parent_id: 1, children: []},
       %Foo{id: 3, parent_id: 2, children: []}]

    expected =
      %Foo{id: 1, parent_id: nil, children: [
        %Foo{id: 2, parent_id: 1, children: [
          %Foo{id: 3, parent_id: 2, children: []},
        ]},
        %Foo{id: 4, parent_id: 1, children: []}
      ]}

    tree =
      list
      |> Enum.reverse
      |> Enum.reduce(%{}, fn foo, map ->
        foo = %{foo | children: Map.get(map, foo.id, [])}
        Map.update(map, foo.parent_id, [foo], fn foos -> [foo | foos] end)
      end)
      |> Map.get(nil)
      |> hd

    IO.inspect tree
    IO.inspect tree == expected
  end
end

Main.main
```

Output:

```
%Foo{children: [%Foo{children: [%Foo{children: [], id: 3, parent_id: 2}], id: 2,
   parent_id: 1}, %Foo{children: [], id: 4, parent_id: 1}], id: 1,
 parent_id: nil}
true
```

Comment: Neat! I had the map idea as well (I did it with a hashmap in Ruby) but wasn't able to implement it that way. Very good idea, thanks!

Comment: I believe this solution only works if the order of `parent_id` corresponds with the depth of the tree. This solution failed for me, for instance, when my id's were UUID's.